# js loading images

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
    var a = new Image();
    a.src = objects.a.image;

    var b = new Image();
    b.src = objects.b.image;

    var x = new Image();
    x.src = objects.x.image;
```

I have about 10 images like this, is there any better way to load it into variables?

Comment: You can use array style

Comment: var objects = {
   'a': {
    'image': '1.png'
   }}

Comment: Few different ways, perhaps a function which you pass the image `src` into as a paramater and then the function returns you your created `img`. Or loop over your object creating an image for each src - depends what your object looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
for(var i in objects)
{
    if(objects[i].image)
    {
        var oImage = new Image();
        oImage.src = objects[i].image;
        // if you need the Image object you can store it somewhere
        objects[i].oImgObject = oImage;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `objects` contains just images, try this:

```
var imageList = [];
for (var i in objects) {
    var obj = objects[i];
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = obj.image;
    imageList.push(img);
}
```

Comment: Or if it contains more than images, add a `if(obj.image) { /* set img.src */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You normally would use an array to store your images.

For example :

```
var arr = [];
for (var c='a'.charCodeAt(0); c<='x'.charCodeAt(0); c++) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = objects[String.fromCharCode(c)].image;
     arr.push(img);
}
```

If you really need to add them as variables to the global context, you might do this :

```
for (var c='a'.charCodeAt(0); c<='x'.charCodeAt(0); c++) {
     var img = new Image();
     var name = String.fromCharCode(c);
     img.src = objects[name].image;
     window[name] = img; // better use somthing's else than window...
}
```

Note that depending on what really is `objects`, there might be a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the properties of your objects object. Creating a new image per iteration, giving it the source of the property on your objects. Then adding it to the array:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dnEKj/)

```
var arrayOfImg = [];

for(var propt in objects){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = objects[propt].image;
    arrayOfImg.push(image)
}

console.log(arrayOfImg);
```